# Is there a better way to 'fake' the href attribute for links?

Tags: javascript, html

Right now I use:

```
href="javascript:void(0)"
```

for my a tags.

However, I find this messy, and it is also displayed to the user in FireFox on a hover.

What I'm considering doing is replacing my links with just plain p tags and setting up event handlers in JavaScript.

**Clarification:**

This is for modern JavaScript enabled browsers only.  I'm not yet currently concerned accessibility.

Comment: sounds like you just answered your own question

Comment: And what about keyboard accessibility? Not everyone uses a mouse to navigate the page.

Comment: what about people with JS disabled/unavailable?

Comment: check out this post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11144653/a-script-links-without-href?rq=1

Comment: Are you trying to cause the cursor to change?  You can do this with CSS: `cursor: pointer`

Comment: sounds obvious to you guys maybe but, why would one create a link to not be used as a link?

Comment: well explaining post (duplicate)[http://stackoverflow.com/questions/134845/href-attribute-for-javascript-links-or-javascriptvoid0][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/134845/href-attribute-for-javascript-links-or-javascriptvoid0

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to disable HTML links](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10276133/how-to-disable-html-links)

Comment: @Sebas - What I ended up doing, but it was a process of conversion ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure what you are trying to do, but you can also use `href="#"` and use unobtrusive javascript to stop the click event from continuing.

Comment: It's an empty hash, but it'll pop the browser up to the top of the window if you don't manage the event.

Comment: Wiki reference: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fragment_identifier or see  RFC 3986

Comment: This is the simplest solution.

Comment: I noticed that the # now displays in the url.

Answer (score 2):

**HTML**:

```
<a href="">Foo</a>
```

**JS**:

```
var a = document.getElementsByTagName('a');
for(i=0 ; i<a.length ; i++){
    a[i].addEventListener('click', function(e) {
        if (this.href === window.location.href) {
            e.preventDefault();
        }
    });
}
```

**Demo**: http://jsfiddle.net/pqNfg/

Comment: I like this version because it keeps clutter out of the DOM and keeps the logic in a script

Comment: your picture scares me.  I'm going to practice that face for when I walk down dark alleys.

Comment: That's Jean-Claude Van Damme from Bloodsport at the end when he's making Chun Li say "Mateeeeeeeeee!!!!!"

Comment: iOS VoiceOver has a nasty habit of reading out links whose href is empty as `visited`

Answer (score 1):

use

`event.preventDefault()` to disable any links that might be initiated by a user clicks

```
anchorElement.onclick=function(e)
{
    e.preventDefault();}
```