# How can I scrape the next page in this DOM where the a tags have no links?

Tags: javascript, python, html, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I'm currently learning how to do web-scraping with python and beautifulsoup and I've run into a bit of a problem.  Here is a link to the [problem page](http://slader.com/subject/math/algebra/textbooks/). At the bottom of the list of all of the books, there is some text that reads "Pages" and then a list of numbers which are the page numbers to continue viewing the rest of the books.  When each number is clicked it updates the page with a new set of books but when I inspect one of the page number elements all I see is this:

```
<a href="#" data-page="3">3</a>
```

I am currently trying to simulate what occurs when you click on one of the numbers and it updates the page with a new set of books.  However, I'm not sure how to do this as there is no url link and there is nothing else hinting at how to update the DOM with the new page.

I believe that the site is doing something similar to what [this guy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11144653/a-script-links-without-href) did where it was explained that he was essentially using the a tag as a button instead.

If anyone has any other info about what is going on here, I'd be tremendously thankful!

Thanks for the help!

Comment: probably made deliberately unscrapable

Comment: I would suggest using Selenium with python.

Comment: It does approx. this: `$(e.target).closest(".pagination").hasClass("facet") ? Slader.Search.searchBySubjectId("", $(".solutions-intro-content").data("subject-id"), Slader.Search.paginationCurrentPage - 1, $(".solutions-intro-content").data("index")) : Slader.Search.doSearch()`. There's much more tools than "Inspect element" in the Dev Tools ...

Comment: I saw that Teemu, I'm just not exactly sure what that is.  Is it javascript code? I'm unfamiliar with it, you're help and clarification is much appreciated!

Comment: Yes, it is JavaScript, it's an event handler executed when a click event occurs on the anchor.

Comment: Okay, is there a way that I could manipulate this so that I could traverse the pages? Or is a "click" necessary in activating this event handler?  Also, what tool did you use to figure this out and what was the process in doing so? I thought I understood what you did but realized I actually do not.  Thanks!

Comment: FireFox Dev Tools, Inspect element, select a number, and the source is shown. There's a small "ev" icon at the end of the line, click that icon and you can see the events attached to the element, clicking on those event lines you can see the actual code.

Comment: Okay thanks for your help Teemu, really appreciate it!